# Code signing for MacOS works in SSH session, but not in Jenkins CI

Tags: jenkins, electron, electron-builder

I build and sign my Electron application on MacOS Catalina using electron-builder 22.3.2.
Works nice in SSH session, fails in Jenkins CI. I already compared all environment variables, and even try to unset some variables in order to hack https://github.com/watson/is-ci test, i.e. simulate 'non-CI' environment. 
It seems that in when called from Jenkins builder removes local keychain *before* using it. Any ideas?

```
executing file=security args=delete-keychain 
/tmp/465cb35e5118c40bc576ed5cfe2207aed7194256a8804498d9a09ba17894a6dd.keychain executed 
file=security Command failed: codesign --sign B6AEB2764D5F34709D0B40E803124C36D12B6E68 -- 
force --keychain 
/tmp/465cb35e5118c40bc576ed5cfe2207aed7194256a8804498d9a09ba17894a6dd.keychain --options 
runtime --entitlements entitlements.mac.plist 

/Users/jenkins/build/workspace/build/mac/xxxxx.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Electron Framework error: The specified item could not be found in the keychain.
```

Comment: Are you setting the CSC_LINK environment variable in Jenkins?

Comment: yes, sure, I had CSC_LINK

Comment: When CSC_LINK is present, electron-builder loads the contents into a temporary keychain and only looks in _that_ keychain -- ignoring the user's keychain. So if Jenkins is providing it and you're not in SSH, or vice versa, that would explain the problem.

Comment: @JakeRobb - first, thank you!
As far as I remember, in both cases  I used CSC_LINK. I.e. I called the same script, with the same commands, either via Jenkins agent, or from the same agent, via "ssh localhost myscript.sh".
And yes, I didn't want to use user's keychain because it's tricky to use it from script.

Comment: Okay. By the sound of it, you're no longer looking for a solution? What did you end up doing?

Comment: >What did you end up doing?
I'm running 
ssh localhost $WORKSPACE/build.sh
instead of 
$WORKSPACE/build.sh